# Nearest point to point A on polygon P in 3D

Tags: geometry

We have given a polygon $P$ which consists of $4$ 3D points $p_1$, $p_2$, $p_3$, $p_4$, the polygon is not necessarily flat. Then let us have a point $A$ (in my case this point is something like a center of mass to polygon $P$ , but the point is not always placed on the polygon). I need to find point $X \in P$ which is the nearest point to point $A$ .

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are $p_1$,$p_2$,$p_3$,$p_4$? Can you think about the vectors perpendicular to the polygon?

Comment: The polygon is usually not flat.

Comment: Please add that information to the question, to help people that may give you an answer. Can you write down a formula that gives you the points in the polygon?

Comment: Well the points are generated from square by moving every point with a random vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be formulated as a [quadratic programming task](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming). Let us introduce a point $\boldsymbol{a}$ and a general point $\boldsymbol{x}$. Then the objective function is given by

$$F(\boldsymbol{x}|\boldsymbol{a})=[\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{a}]^T[\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{a}].\qquad (*)$$

We additionally need to assume that the polygon is flat. If it is not flat we will need to further differentiate the problem. Then we determine the normal vector $\boldsymbol{n}$ of the polygon by using the cross product of two vectors which are aligned with the edges of the polygon. Then we know that every point in the polygon needs to fulfill the following equality constraint

$$\boldsymbol{n}^T[\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{p}_1 ]=0,\qquad (**)$$

in which $\boldsymbol{p}_1$ is a corner point of the polygon. Then we construct the outward edge normal for all the edges I will call them $\boldsymbol{n}_1$ for the edge $\boldsymbol{p}_1$ to $\boldsymbol{p}_2$, $\boldsymbol{n}_2$ for the edge $\boldsymbol{p}_2$ to $\boldsymbol{p}_3$, and so forth. In order to achieve this we will need to take the cross product of the polygon normal $\boldsymbol{n}$ and the edge vectors.

Then we use these outward normal vectors to span an additional hyperplane for each edge. We will have the following inequality

$$\boldsymbol{n}^T_i[\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{p}_i]\geq 0.\qquad (***).$$

Then we can formulate our quadratic programming problem as

$$\text{minimize } [\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{a}]^T[\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{a}]$$
$$\text{subject to: } \boldsymbol{n}^T[\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{p}_1 ]=0 \quad \text{and} \quad
\boldsymbol{n}^T_i[\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{p}_i]\geq 0 \quad \forall i=1,2,3,4$$

Comment: Well in my case the polygon is not necessarily flat...

Comment: @mathys: Then split the polygon into flat triangles if it is possible. The same procedure is applicable for arbitrary flat polygons. If the area is not flat even for triangles you will need to define the shape of the surface. An alternative would be to approximate the surface by many triangles and do the previous calculations and determine the point that has minimal distance from all these points. Then project the corresponding point onto the surface of your nonflat polygon.

Comment: That came to my mind but there is a problem how to split the polygon. It might be enough to split it into two triangles but how to determine which?

Comment: You have to split it where the surface bends.

Comment: Yeah but is there a way to find out where it is without looking at the graph?

Comment: Yes use two edge vectors that are connected to an edge and span a hyperplane through these vectors then theck if the other edges are inside this hyperplane. If not there must be a bend towards the next edges.

Comment: Thanks man, it worked!